# How to Force application.css to refresh in Rails 2.3.9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, refresh

I've tried a whole variety of answers listed, including
"How to prevent browsers from caching a page in Rails".

I've added a random number to the end of the filename -

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application.css?123456' %>
(which generates
  &lt;link href="/stylesheets/application.css?123456" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

- still no luck!)

I've used

```
&lt;style type=\"text/css\">@import url('/stylesheets/application.css');&lt;/style>
```

I look at the file on the server, looks good.
I look at it via the browser (http://www.mysite.com/stylesheets/application.css)
and I see the old file!  On IE8 and Firefox 14.

I use capistrano to deploy: rake tmp:cache:clear is run during restart.
I've set, in  config/environments/production.rb,
config.cache_classes = false
and
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = false

(sigh...)

Host is Linux, Apache, Passenger, Rails.

This is hugely frustrating, now.  It's been many, many hours!
None of the answers seem to be working.
I am become ... Desparate!

I expect I'll be flabergasted by the answer, probably very simple.
Nonetheless, any other suggestions!
PLEASE! Your assistance will be most appreciated.

PS>  Love this site.  Many many answers Have been found over the years!

Comment: This sounds like it has more to do with your Apache settings more than your Rails app.

Comment: Have you tried re-deployment.

Comment: Thanks.  It was after re-deployment I noticed the problem.  Development works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use assets (But they are only in Rails 3). Each time you deploy your applications assets will be compiled in css/js files, already minified and with unique name.[Ruby On Rails Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

There is one more useful tip. Setup proxy server like Nginx in front of your app server and set "expire" for static files, so browser will refetch file if it is expired.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I understand about Rails 3.  Not an option at this time.  My service provider manages everything on the shared machine.  (Site5 host.)  I'll ask them about expiring files.  Maybe it's a Passenger/Apache level issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in fact, with my service provider!

I use capistrano to deploy.
It uses a symlink "current" to point to the current release folder
(releases/201210109993333/, or whatever, a datetime value).

I use subdomain redirection, and used "current/public" as part of the path to each site.
Somehow, all my "current" values got replaced with their actual values!!!!
i.e, in my redirection, it said ".../releases/201210109993333/public".
WOW.  So any static assets were being fed from a historical folder, rather than the current one.
The substitution happened when they migrated to a new machine.  Looking at the dates (release folders) substitued, I'm sure that's what happened.  They agreed.

Thanks everyone for your support!

Answer (score -3):

Try to update your rails. Just a suggestion.

Comment: This really doesn't even try to answer the questions. Might be appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Updating Rails not a current option.  Maybe in a year.  Has to work with current version.  I need a solution for Rails 2.3.9.  Thanks.